# Clockworkmod doesn't find the update files

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I recently added a 16GB storage card to my phone and set it as an extension to the internal memory using the built-in tool in Cyanogenmod 13. But now, the recovery can not find the update files anymore. I can only open the /storage/sdcard folder, but when I try to open /storage/sdcard/0 to access the cmupdater folder, it says that there are no files in there. I can install updates using adb commands though. How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For future Visitors: just install the [TWRP recovery](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24499762636003169) on your phone(I used the [Flashify app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify)from the Play Store to install). Look for the folders there. I found what I looked for in /sdcard. With TWRP, it should be very easy to install the update.

Comment: Could you describe what you did? That would be helpful to any future visitors who are googling for the same problem.